# Laravel Scheduler (withoutOverlapping)

Tags: laravel

I have two apps running on the same server.
Now it seems like when adding `withoutOverlapping()` to the scheduler job and managing the base cronjob via cron itself, these 2 apps are blocking each other in execution.
Could that be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `withoutOverlapping` only works per application.

Laravel creates a file in the storage folder with a hash of the job. This way, if the file exists, Laravel knows the job is still running. The one application cannot possibly know if the other one is currently running a job because it does not have access to the storage folder of the other application.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but what i experiencing is exactly the opposit you described.
If i have both apps with a scheduler for the queue work, then it seems like one app blocks the execution of the other.

Answer (score 0):

If your code looks like the following

```
$schedule->command('process:queue 0')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
$schedule->command('process:queue 1')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

It is because same commands with different parameters might bc considered overlapping.

I.e. the hash of the job will consider only the command signature.